# Is it possible to download a Google data archive for an account on a Google Apps domain?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, export

Google [now provides](http://gmailblog.blogspot.ca/2013/12/download-copy-of-your-gmail-and-google.html) the capability to download an archive of one's Gmail and other data. This appears to be available for my `@gmail.com` account, but I also have a domain being managed by Google Apps. Is it possible to download a similar archive for the user accounts in my domain? I can't find any such option in either the admin account's or the individual users' Account settings...

Answer (score -1):

I am hoping for the same thing as well as incremental downloads.  For now, I am able to log in as any user with myUsername+theirUsername and myPassword on our customized login page using GAIL.

Comment: How does this answer the question?